# get data from s3 Bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, bucket

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if event:
        # TODO implement
        params=event.get('city')

        print(params)
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        data = s3.get_object(Bucket='clg-data' ,Key='citiescsv.csv')

        file = data['body'].read().decode('utf-8')
        print(file)
```

This is my code

```
    {"errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied", "errorType": "ClientError",  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 15, in lambda_handler\n    data = s3.get_object(Bucket='clg-data',Key='citiescsv.csv')\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 357, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 676, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n" ]}
```

I got this error while getting the data from the bucket.

Comment: What is your lambda execution role?

Comment: just to get the csv file from bucket

Comment: Hi. I noticed that you have several questions with answers, yet not a single one was accepted. If all of them were not helpful, its fine. But if they helped, accepting them is a good practice. It eliminates number of duplicate questions and helps others if future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message writes "GetObject operation: Access Denied" which most likely means that your [lambda execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html) does not have S3 read permissions. You can rectify this by adding the following [inline policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#inline-policies) to the lambda's role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::clg-data/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Other reasons are also possible, e.g. lambda needs KMS permissions as bucket is encrypted or bucket is not in your account.